# Sonos Soap Envelope example that includes SessionId

Tags: sonos

Trying to implement a Soap header handler I need a specific example of a Soap request that the Sonos client will make which includes the SessiondId.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are deprecating support for sessionid-based authentication. It will continue to work, but future integrations should be built using app linking.

In the meantime, a sessionid-container header would contain this credentials object:

```
  <ns:credentials>
     <ns:deviceId>00:00:00:00:00</ns:deviceId>
     <ns:deviceProvider>Sonos</ns:deviceProvider>
     <ns:sessionId>[sessionIdentifier]</ns:sessionId>
  </ns:credentials>
```